# isbn de-duplicate with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Brief background**: I retrieve book info from google books *and* worldcat via each api. I parse through the data to create an html div outputs with stuff of interest for a webapp.

**The problem: the isbns**. After getting isbns from each, I merge them into one div. For example:

`<span id='tada'>9781137012920 9780230339118 9781137012920 1137012927</span>`

I would like to eliminate the duplicate isbn (e.g., 9781137012920) with either javascript or jquery. I can get the text of the span but every solution I have tried has failed thus far.

Any help - esp, with a codepen or fiddle - for this amateur would be greatly appreciated.

*PS:I know variations of this question have been addressed on StackOverflow - and believe me that I am sick of duplicates! - but I have not managed to fix this after a couple of days of trying. Examples that type in the content as var work but how do I get it from the div and make it work?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this using **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)** method with callback

```js
$('span').text(function(i, v) { // use callback to get old value
  return v.split(' ') // split the old value
    .filter(function(v1, i, arr) { // v1 is array element, i is index, arr is iterating array
      return arr.indexOf(v1) == i; // filter unique value by checking the index
    }).join(' ') // join and return the unique values
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='tada'>9781137012920 9780230339118 9781137012920 1137012927</span>
```

For more about finding unique array element refer : [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I will try not to think too much about the fact that it took me two days of not getting this right ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the duplicates before making them into the div. If you are getting the values in an array you can eliminate the duplicates easily. [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: I will absolutely try to learn from that too. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this :

```js
var string = $('span').text();

var uniqueList=string.split(' ').filter(function(allItems,i,a){
    return i==a.indexOf(allItems);
}).join(' ');

$('#output').append(uniqueList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h1>Input</h1>
  <span>9781137012920 9780230339118 9781137012920 1137012927</span>
</div>
<div id="output">
    <h1>Becomes</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your step by step are quite helpful for me. A world of thanks

Comment: Good to know it helped :)